# Width of contentview change of size, even when a value is given

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a contentview inside the next stacklayout:

```
<StackLayout Padding="0" x:Name="VisualColumn" WidthRequest="{Binding widthColumn,Source={x:Reference DeliveryPage}}">

</StackLayout>
```

DeliveryPage is the name of the contentpage and the property widthColums is declared like this:

```
public double widthCol
    {
        get {
            if (widthScreen < heightScreen)
            {
                return Constants.ScreenWidth * 0.3;
            }
            return Constants.ScreenHeight * 0.3;
        }
    }
```

Widthscreen and heightscreen only change when the phone is turned.

Inside the stacklayout "VisualColumn" there is a contentview, that can show different stacklayouts, with their own labels, but the with is different for the 3 sections that can show. Why this happens?

Comment: Default HorizontalOptions for StackLayout is Fill, which doesn't respect the WidthRequest. You should try changing it to Center/Start/End

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation of [`WidthRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.WidthRequest?view=xamarin-forms)

> The width this element **desires** to be. [emphasis mine]

If there are other constraints that make it impossible to fulfil the request, it's possible that you end up with `WidthRequest` being ignored.

I don't know your exact layout, but I think that there are other options to achieve what you want, I will sketch two of those:

#### Using a `Grid`

With a `Grid` there are quite some options to fine-tune your layout. Especially with the `*` width (or height). A column given the width `*` will take the space that is available. If there are multiple columns with a `*` width, they will device the available space equally. Anyway, you can use multiples of `*`. Having one column with `*` and one with `2*` means that they take the available space with the second one having twice the size of the first one

```
 *    2*
+----+--------+
|    |        |
|    |        |
```

In your case (you want the column to take 30% of the available space), you could have one column with `3*` and another one with `7*` (or `3*`, `3*`, and `4*`; just make sure that they sum up to `10` if the first one should take 30%).

```
 3*     7*
+------+--------------+
|      |              |
|      |              |
```

#### Using an `AbsoluteLayout`

Another very flexible option is to use an [`AbsoluteLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.absolutelayout?view=xamarin-forms)

> Positions child elements at absolute positions.

With an `AbsoluteLayout` you can directly control positions and sizes of the children of the layout. E.g. if you'd like to control the width of a `StackLayout` only and position it at `(0, 0)` you can use the following code

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional, PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,.3,-1">
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

The `LayoutBounds="0,0,.3,-1"` is telling the `AbsoluteLayout` to position the `StackLayout` at `0,0` and the the width to 30% (`.3`). The height of the child will not be set (`-1`).

Comment: thanks for your response, now is a little late but tomorrow morning I will check it out,